# Unable to install Supervisor on shared hosting

Tags: linux, cpanel, shared-hosting

I am trying to install [supervisor](http://supervisord.org/) to keep my jobs running .. this is my first time using it and as far as i understand i should first enter `apt-get install supervisor` from the terminal. Please note i am using a shared hosting but it provides me an online terminal inside the cPanel but `apt-get install` is not working or `sudo apt-get install` or `yum install`

What am i missing or is there an alternative way to get it installed ?

[image]

Comment: Maybe your PATH variable doesn't include /usr/bin? What if you issue `/usr/bin/sudo`, i.e. the full path?

Comment: Also, what does `command -V sudo` output, and likewise for `command -V apt-get`?  And, of course, `echo $PATH`?

Comment: If this is truly shared hosting, it is super unlikely you’ll be able to install software let alone run custom daemons.

Answer (score 2):

Because you used yum in your question I am assuming that you are on CentOS, Fedora, RHEL or a related distribution that has rpm-based package management. Open the terminal and type:

```
su
yum install sudo    
yum install supervisor
```

If that doesn't work then you will need to add the repository that has supervisor to your OS's software sources. Please  provide the name of the Linux distro that you are using. If you are using a Debian-based Linux distro, the commands to run are as follows:

```
su
apt install sudo  
apt install supervisor
```

If you are using Ubuntu, supervisor is in the universe repository. The commands to enable the universe repository (required to install supervisor) are:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe  
sudo update
```

In Debian supervisor is in the main repository which is enabled by default, so there is no need to enable it.

Supervisor is a system for controlling and maintaining process state,  similar to what init does, but not intended as an init replacement.

It will manage individual processes or groups of processes that need to be started and stopped in order, and it is possible to control individual process state via an rpc mechanism, thus allowing ordinary users to restart processes.